# App compiles for a simulator but not a physical device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode12

Recently I tried integrating a pod but as soon as I do I get this error:

> `ld: in /Users/bentran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nervy-ggvazspfamkfqmgbpaglrqonunrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UXCam.framework/UXCam(UXCam.o), building for iOS, but linking in object file (/Users/bentran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nervy-ggvazspfamkfqmgbpaglrqonunrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UXCam.framework/UXCam(UXCam.o)) built for iOS Simulator, file '/Users/bentran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nervy-ggvazspfamkfqmgbpaglrqonunrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UXCam.framework/UXCam' for architecture arm64`

Ive seen many other stackoverflow posts talking about this issue but in reverse (app compiles for physical device but not for simulator). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit:
Running lipo -info /Users/bentran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nervy-ggvazspfamkfqmgbpaglrqonunrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UXCam.framework/UXCam

Produces:
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/bentran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nervy-ggvazspfamkfqmgbpaglrqonunrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UXCam.framework/UXCam are: arm64 x86_64 i386

Comment: Your pod has to have an x86_64 version of the pod for it to work with simulator. It is best to look at the information for the pod to see if it is supported or for instructions on how to support it.

Comment: Also, if you do have both make sure in Project/Targets>Bulid Settings>Build Active Architectures>Debug>Yes so you aren't building the arm64 when all you need is the x86_64

Comment: Yea the pod works completely fine on the simulator but doesn’t seem to build for a physical device. I know it can work for a physical device because there is another project that I have with the same pod installed which works fine on a physical device. I also did make sure that the build active architectures only was set to true. Still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Are you including the same framework twice maybe, i.e once statically, and once via PODs? also check which architectures that file includes (`lipo -info [full path to UXCam.o`). and add the answer to your question

Comment: Ive edited my question to include the output of lipo -info. I dont think the framework is included twice because if I try to import it without the pod being installed, then I get a framework not found error. @KirilS.

Comment: `UXCam` looks like a good fat file...  Does your project include building for `armv7` by any chance? because `UXCam` does not include it. And honestly, unless you are including really old devices (below iPhone 5s I think), you don't need it

Comment: Also I'd try a complete clean: clean build directory, delete Derived Data, `pod deintegrate && pod install` and see if you are still getting the same error

Comment: Just tried removing support for armv7 and doing a complete clean. Unfortunately still the same issue :(.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.
Updating the react-native-ux-cam package to version 5.3.1, then updating the pods solved it.